# iPhone not showing multiple backgrounds?

Tags: iphone, css, mobile-safari

I'm having issues with this particular site not showing one of the backgrounds. I didn't design the site and it just got handed to me today.

But the URL is: http://musicalchairswc.com/

The CSS is:

```
div.body_wrapper {
  background-image:url(img/big_bg_mod.jpg), url(img/bg_gradient.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat, repeat-y;
  background-position: center -25px, center top;

}
```

But on an iPhone, the first background (img/big_bg_mod.jpg) doesn't show up. As far as my understanding goes - Mobile Safari now supports multiple backgrounds, yes?

Thanks beforehand for any pointers.

Comment: My iphone currently runs iOS 5.1 and it has that missing background problem as well.

Comment: I've started to think that it's the image size that's too big (2600px x 2600px). Replaced with another for testing and it showed up. Does it make sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the fine documentation.

http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15

> The maximum decoded image size for JPEG is 32 megapixels using subsampling.

Here is the way I would approach it.

```
div.body_wrapper {
  background-image:url(img/big_bg_mod_1-1.jpg), url(img/big_bg_mod_1-2.jpg), url(img/big_bg_mod_1-3.jpg), url(img/bg_gradient.jpg);
  background-repeat:no-repeat, repeat-y;
  background-position: center -25px, center 1000px, center 2000px, center top;
}
```

I split big_bg_mod.jpg (2320x1000, 2320x1000, 2320x320)